# JHIPSTER OKTA invalid_id_token

Tags: jhipster, okta

I followed the steps on JHIPSTER to setup okta. When I try to login I always get the following output:

```
Login with OAuth 2.0
[invalid_id_token]
https://dev-992900.okta.com/oauth2/default
```

I cant resolve it. Additionally, I would prefer to be using a google identity provider. I am not sure how to setup the google identity provider, and additionally I cant even get the login setup correctly.

Please advise how to find answer for issue 1.

Deleted and re setup the configuration as per JHIPSTER documentation for okta setup. I tried adding my email to the groups, and tried it without a user added, with a user added.

Login with OAuth 2.0
[invalid_id_token]
https://dev-992900.okta.com/oauth2/default

```
  security:
oauth2:
  client:
    provider:
      oidc:
        issuer-uri: https://dev-992900.okta.com/oauth2/default
    registration:
      oidc:
        client-id: 0oa1aykbfvUKOJN4S357
        client-secret: gpuNPCPBQWl_JJLAMZh6fFlc1XyuBoCTtKtm2JYD
```

[OKTA CONFIG SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bb2V.png)

[OKTA CONFIG SCREENSHOT 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKvTo.png)

[OKTA CONFIG SCREENSHOT 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3MDM.png)

[OKTA CONFIG SCREENSHOT 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyZXg.png)

I followed okta tutorial here: https://www.jhipster.tech/security/ and it does not work. Additionally I would prefer to use google identity service.

Comment: I've had this happen before when my client ID doesn't match the OIDC app in Okta.

Comment: what does that mean, im a noob. What is required to resolve that issue. you make a app and it gives you a client id, then put in application.yml, then should work, but does not. They do match as far as i know.

Comment: so, i followed all tutorials and what not and it doesnt work :(

Comment: alright, im going crazy, this does not work at all with jhipster.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this is totally awesome, infuriating, and what drives me crazy. I found the issue which is now resolved. I set my windows 10 pc to automatic time. I cannot believe it was that, but I guess thats why token was invalid. It was the correct time but it wasnt set to automatic time sync. I had automatic timezone set though. I literally spent weeks stalled because of this :|

[time automatic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqTjv.png)